# Fill the cell with a formula if it's blank

Tags: excel, vba

I got a cell which has the formula: `=SE(G15<>"";0;"")` , it means depending the reference cell isn't blank, **it must returns me a 0 in the that cell.**

The thing is, sometimes I will have to manually change this cell to another numeric value, erasing the old formula I put, and then in the future this cell will never returns me the 0 again in case I don't put the same formula again.

I want to make a vba code which helps me in that. Every time I delete the cell with the value I put manually, it brings back the formula with the 0, and this in the range `F16:Q16`.

What I was trying to write is something like:

`Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`

and define the `target.range` for each cell, but I don't know how to progress anymore.

Please, can someone help in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the worksheet change event:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("F16:Q16")) 'range to be checked
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo haveError
        Application.EnableEvents = False 'stop updates from re-triggering this handler
        For Each c In rng.Cells
            If Not c.HasFormula And Len(c.Value) = 0 Then
                c.Formula = "=IF(G15<>"""",0,"""")" 'use US-style from VBA
                                                    ' or use FormulaLocal
            End If
        Next c
    End If

haveError:
    Application.EnableEvents = True 'make sure events are re-enabled
End Sub
```